# Python add multiple lists to list

Tags: python, list

I have this function that can append the first three columns of data to a new empty list. Example output is:

```
['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black']
```

I would like to enclose every two elements of this list in its own list i.e.

```
[['red', 'blue'], ['green', 'yellow'], ['purple', 'black']]
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

```
def selection_table(table):
    atts = [1,2,3]
    new_table = []
    for row in table:
        for i in range(len(new_atts)):
            new_table.append(row[atts[i]])
    return new_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black']
>>> result = (my_list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2))
>>> list(result)
[['red', 'blue'], ['green', 'yellow'], ['purple', 'black']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) question:

```
a = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black']

def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

print(list(chunks(a, 2)))
```

Gives:

```
[['red', 'blue'], ['green', 'yellow'], ['purple', 'black']]
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way is use zip :)

```
test=['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black']
c=zip(test[0::2],test[1::2])
map(lambda x :list(x),c)
>>>>[['red', 'blue'], ['green', 'yellow'], ['purple', 'black']]
```

OR

```
test=['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black']
map(lambda x :list(x),zip(test[0::2],test[1::2]))
```

Comment: Actually, if he wants to get a list of list instead of list of tupples, the proper answer is: `[list(x) for x in zip(test[0::2], test[1::2])]`

Comment: @shutoutzilla37 try this answer